# How do I properly use DI with IHttpClientFactory in .NET MAUI

Tags: httpclient, maui, .net-maui

I haven't found anything about HttpClient in .NET MAUI.

Does anyone know if the service:
`builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IMyService, MyService>();`
is possible in MAUI's startup MauiProgram.cs? And then inject HttpClient to where it's going to be used. I have tried everything and it does not seem to work. Only AddSingleton of HttpClient works for me, but it doesn't seem optimal.

PS.: I had to install nuget package Microsoft.Extensions.Http in order to use the AddHttpClient service.

**UPDATES**:

WORKING CODE:

**MauiProgram.cs**

```cs
builder.Services.AddTransient<Service<Display>, DisplayService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<Service<Video>, VideoService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<Service<Image>, ImageService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<Service<Log>, LogService>();

builder.Services.AddSingleton(sp => new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.myapi.com") });
```

**Example of VideosViewModel.cs using a service**

```cs
[INotifyPropertyChanged]
public partial class VideosViewModel
{
    readonly Service<Video> videoService;
    
    [ObservableProperty]
    ObservableCollection<Video> videos;

    [ObservableProperty]
    bool isEmpty;
    
    [ObservableProperty]
    bool isRefreshing;
    
    public VideosViewModel(Service<Video> videoService)
    {
        this.videoService = videoService;
    }

    [ICommand]
    internal async Task LoadVideosAsync()
    {
#if ANDROID || IOS || tvOS || Tizen
        UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Henter videoer fra databasen...");
#endif
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        
        Videos = new();

        try
        {
            await foreach (Video video in videoService.GetAllAsync().OrderBy(x => x.Id))
            {
                Videos.Add(video);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            IsRefreshing = false;
#if ANDROID || IOS || tvOS
            UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
#endif

            if (Videos.Count is 0)
            {
                IsEmpty = true;
            }
            else
            {
                IsEmpty = false;
            }
        }
    }
    
    [ICommand]
    async Task UploadVideoAsync()
    {
        await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Upload en video", "Under opbygning - kommer senere!", "OK");
    }
}
```

NOT WORKING CODE:

**MauiProgram.cs**

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<Service<Display>, DisplayService>(sp => sp.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.myapi.com"));
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<Service<Video>, VideoService>(sp => sp.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.myapi.com"));
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<Service<Image>, ImageService>(sp => sp.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.myapi.com"));
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<Service<Log>, LogService>(sp => sp.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.myapi.com"));
```

**VideosViewModel.cs**
Same as above working code.

What specifically doesn't work is that I get object reference exception on OrderBy(x => x.Id), specifically highlighted x.Id in ViewModel. Removing OrderBy method gives no longer exceptions, but the view shows no data except one random empty Frame.

Comment: I edited the post and posted more info @ToolmakerSteve When I run it, it just says "object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: It shows System.IO.FileNotFoundException: '' when checking all CLR exceptions and running app, I clicked "Continue" when debugging despite this exception, and had to click Continue a couple more times before my app would run. Now I can see my object null reference, it's at "OrderBy(x => x.Id)" in my LoadImagesAsync method, specifically highlighted on x.Id. And I tried now deleting OrderBy() ext.-method, and it works with no errors, but now there's no data shown except one item of no values (an empty Frame in my view).

Comment: Good. I think that is telling you that imageService returned a "null" instead of one of the images. You'll have to do more debugging to determine which one it is. That FileNotFoundException sounds like a good place to start.

Comment: But my app runs perfectly fine with AddSingleton and not on AddHttpClient, which I'm confused by

Comment: Show the code that does work. It sounds like multiple HttpClients doesn't work. Perhaps there is a way to specify HttpClient as a singleton, then add those Services to it.

Comment: If you know if HttpClient can be singleton through AddHttpClient and how it's done, I would try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use builder.Services.AddHttpClient in MAUI.
Use one instance.

Comment: What if you have multiple endpoints?

Comment: @ledragon Single instance.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Can you direct me to any implementation examples? I've actually come across a previous post of yours before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76247721/how-to-create-a-non-shell-app-in-net-maui#comment134465515_76247721 ...you're not kidding huh! I tried and gave up and am now using Shell now I understand how to use it for my needs. Anyway appreciate any direction you can give on the above. What I'm trying to accomplish is explained in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77753380/maui-addhttpclient-and-addsingleton-outside-of-createmauiapp

Answer (score 1):

builder.Services.AddHttpClient works for me. Here is how I setup mine: in the main program, I added .AddHttpClient()

```
public static class MauiProgram
{
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
    builder
        .UseMauiApp<App>()
        .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
        {
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
        });

 #if DEBUG
    builder.Logging.AddDebug();
 #endif

    return builder.Build();
}
}
```

And in AppShell.xaml I removed the DataTemplate definition, made it barebone like this:

```
<Shell
    x:Class="MAUIMultiPage.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MAUIMultiPage"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">

    <TabBar>
        <ShellContent
        x:Name="homepage"
        Title="Home"
         />
        <ShellContent
        x:Name="specialOpsPage"
        Title="Special Ops"
         />

    </TabBar>

</Shell>
```

Notice that I gave an x:Name to the ShellContents. The DataTemplates are defined in the code behind of AppShell.xaml where I can pass a Func object with IHttpClientFactory as a DI parameter, which looks like this:

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        homepage.ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => new MainPage(httpClientFactory));
        specialOpsPage.ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => new SpecialOps(httpClientFactory));
    }
}
```

For the App class we can inject IHttpClientFactory, which is passed to AppShell:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new AppShell(httpClientFactory);
    }
}
```

And in each individual page I would have iHttpClientFactory available from the Func DI parameter

```
  public partial class SpecialOps : ContentPage
   {
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

        public SpecialOps(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this._httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
        }
    
        private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            var result = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees");
            txtResult.Text = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
```

A complete solution for this example is in my GitHub repository: https://github.com/yogigrantz/MAUIWithHttpClientFactory