# How to create a NON Shell App in .NET MAUI?

Tags: maui

We have made a decision that using Shell navigation is just a little restrictive and cumbersome and we are going to utilize our own Flyout pages which are not allowed in shell apps BUT when we move to create a new app, there is no option to create a shell/non shell app??? So we created default app then simply deleted the appshell object which seems to work BUT is this all that is required in order for us to utilize our own flyout pages?

Comment: *"then simply deleted the appshell object which seems to work"* -  
PLEASE show the actual code change you made. Otherwise, its impossible to say whether you made the correct change or not!

Comment: This isn't really a well written question. You may want to read up on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Instead of just describing what you did, it's better to show what you did.

Comment: Perhaps I should ask a question on how to ask a question??? :-) Apologies ... I literally deleted the Appshell objects (XAML and CS) and in App.xaml.cs changed MainPage = new AppShell() to MainPage = new MainPage();

Comment: "We have made a decision that using Shell navigation is just a little restrictive" - this is a mistake. This here: MainPage = new MainPage(); - even bigger. I wont try to convince you about the time it saves, or why you should be using Dependency Injection and not call "new". Not going to try to explain to you how much harder it will be to organize passing of objects, or writing your own navigation. (because every such point is worth separate discussion) All I am saying to you - sit and talk again, and make sure you know what you are facing.

Comment: Yes, you can delete the appshell.xaml and appshell.cs file and then use the `MainPage = new MainPage()` in the app.cs to create a non shell app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its as simple as changing `MainPage = new AppShell();`in App.xaml.cs, to whatever you want:

- `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MyFirstPage());` if you want to use [NavigationPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/navigationpage)'s navigation features.
- Otherwise simply `MainPage = new MyFirstPage();`, and then roll your own page changes via `Application.Current.MainPage = new SomeOtherPage();`.

Substitute the appropriate class name for `MyFirstPage`. E.g. in the Maui template, it is `class MainPage`, so use `MainPage` if you want to immediately test a new Maui project.

Note that both these solutions involve explicitly calling `new YourPageNameHere()` rather than relying on Dependency Injection. This may affect code you need to write elsewhere (compared to Maui examples you'll find, which tend to rely on DI).